# Git - Maintain different composer/npm plugin versions

Tags: git, npm, composer-php

Recently I upgraded some of my plugins (most importantly Laravel and its dependencies).
Afterwards I experienced some problems and wanted to switch back to my stable branch.
I quickly realized my mistake - vendor and npm directories are ignored so switching the branch is useless.
This made me wonder if there is a good way to switch back to an old version of npm/composer plugins as if we were switching the branch **without** unignore the directories?
Obviously I simply could reinstall everything but this seems very uneconomic and time consuming. Additionally I'm dependent on a mobile internet connection atm, so every Bit counts and I want to prevent any unnecessary download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This made me wonder if there is a good way to switch back to an old version of npm/composer plugins as if we were switching the branch without unignore the directories?

You can use `git worktree` instead of working on a single folder

#### `git worktree`

`worktree` allows you to have **multiple instances** of the same repository across **different folders**.

```
git worktree add <second path>
```

will create another folder on your computer which allows you to work on different branch simultaneously in which you can install your npm and you don't need to remove/switch to a different branch.

[image]

`git worktree` will create a new working folder allow us to work on multiple branches on the same time. each copy will point to the origin repository while the `3-states` is a new and fresh copy. This save us the need to use `git stash` or even to clone a new repository since those worktree shares the same repo we can checkout any branch on any worktree, we can do a cherry-pick or merge and all will be done locally on our machine.

This will allow you do to any experiments on the new worktree without having any effect on the repository itself.
In the attached image you can see that there are **2 separate** working folder but both of them are using a single repo and share the content.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. I noticed that git created a new branch, named after the new working tree folder. Is there a specific reason for that? I don't see why this would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With NPM, you can install specific versions by appending @ to the package name, e.g. `npm install lodash@4.17.4`

Composer has something similar: `composer require vendor/package:version`

This may allow you to install only what you need to get back to a working state.

Comment: But this would mean that I still have to **download** these versions again. Of course I have composer.json and package.json files in which I set the wanted version.